# How to keep a dictionary of dictionaries (or something with similar functionality) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

So I have a large dataframe with many columns. Let us say the two main columns I am interested are messages and names. Each message will be something like a personal status and will be accompanied by the person's name. Let's say I have a word bank of emotion/feeling words which is fairly huge but a condensed version could look like ['sad', 'happy', 'relieved', 'annoyed', 'angry', 'ecstatic', 'proud', 'disappointed']. For each name (and names could be repeated since they could have multiple messages), I want to keep track of the emotion words they have used and their accompanying counts. For example (I have made this up since I have a really large dataset):

```
Message                                      Name
I am really happy with my progress.          Alice
I was annoyed by his inconsideration.        John
I felt proud after seeing her performance.   Lisa
I am ecstatic after hearing the good news.   Alice
I felt disappointed by her dishonesty        Lisa
```

If I wanted something that would essentially tell me the following (I don't necessarily care about the format as long as it's clean): {Alice: happy:1, ecstatic: 1; John: annoyed:1; Lisa: proud:1, disappointed: 1}.

What is the best/easiest way of doing this? Is a dictionary of dictionaries the best way to do this? Secondly (this is sort of an additional related question), after computing above, what if I wanted to find the most frequently used emotion word for each name. In this example everything is pretty much tied at 1, but imagine the counts were not the same.

Comment: If a single row has `message` twice, do you want to count it as one or two?

Comment: As in, for example, the message for a single row has "happy" twice? I hadn't really thought of that, but twice is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a very *easy* way of accomplishing what you are looking for, I would suggest using the pandas [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) functionality in combination with the [collections utility](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

## Initial Situation

```
df = pd.read_csv('messages.csv')
df['Emotion Words'] = df.Message.apply(extract_emotion_words)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                      Message   Name   Emotion Words
0         I am really happy with my progress.  Alice         [happy]
1      I am really happy with johns progress.  Alice         [happy]
2       I was annoyed by his inconsideration.   John       [annoyed]
3  I felt proud after seeing her performance.   Lisa         [proud]
4  I am ecstatic after hearing the good news.  Alice      [ecstatic]
5       I felt disappointed by her dishonesty   Lisa  [disappointed]
```

## Group By Name and Apply Counter

```
from collections import Counter
df.groupby('Name')['Emotion Words'].sum().apply(Counter)
```

**Output:**

```
Name
Alice        {'happy': 2, 'ecstatic': 1}
John                      {'annoyed': 1}
Lisa     {'disappointed': 1, 'proud': 1}
dtype: object
```

## Get Most Frequent Word

Since you also indicated that you want to get the most common emotion word, you can use the `Counter.most_common(n)` function where `n` is the number of most common words to extract (in your case 1):

```
df.groupby('Name')['Emotion Words'].sum().apply(
   lambda words: Counter(words).most_common(1)
)
```

**Output:**

```
Name
Alice           [(happy, 2)]
John          [(annoyed, 1)]
Lisa     [(disappointed, 1)]
dtype: object
```

For this little example, I used the following function to extract the emotion words. There sure might be better ways of doing it (perhaps you are already using the [nltk](http://www.nltk.org), if not I would suggest you look into it).

```
import re

emotionWords = set(['sad', 'happy', 'relieved', 'annoyed', 'angry', 'ecstatic', 'proud', 'disappointed'])

def extract_emotion_words(message):
    tokenized = re.split(r'\W+', message.lower())
    return list(set(tokenized) & emotionWords)
```

Comment: This looks great! Thank you!! If you don't mind helping a bit more, could you briefly explain the `df.groupby('Name')['Emotion Words'].sum().apply(Counter)` line a little more? I get that you are grouping the emotion words by name, but I am a little unsure how the `.sum().apply(Counter)` works. Also, what if I wanted to get the maximum occuring emotion word per name? Again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JaneSully yes sure, when you are grouping data, you have to provide an aggregation function. if you compare this to numeric values, you might want to aggregate by taking the median. for a number of lists (our emotion words) we "sum" which means in this case concatenating the individual lists (so `['happy'] + ['proud']` gets `['happy', 'proud']`). afterwards we apply the `Counter` to it which results in this "frequency table".

Comment: that makes complete sense. Thanks for the clear explanation. Last question, if you can help a bit more. If I wanted to find the max occurring word for each name (imagine the counts for happy and disappointed were two), so I'd want to return something Alice: happy, John: annoyed, and Lisa: disappointed, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: @JaneSully i just added an example on how to get the most frequent word

Comment: thank you. That's so simple. You have been SO HELPFUL!

Comment: Another question for you. The groupby and apply run time appears to be very slow together. I was trying it with a subset of my dataset, but when I use it on the full dataset, it refuses to run in a timely manner. Are there other methods/approaches that have the same functionality that are faster? Thank you!